# dispatch custom event for component doesnt have parent

Tags: apache-flex, events, actionscript, event-handling

i have a Group g1 that addElement MyComponent comp1 and a UIComponent c1 add child g1
and a custom Event customEvent1 means:

```
c1.addChild(g1.addElement(comp1))
```

so comp1.parent is null

this is some code

MyComponent:

```
private function mouseUpFunction(e:MouseEvent):void {
    //e.stopPropagation();
    var event:MouseChangeEvent = new MouseChangeEvent(MouseChangeEvent.Mouse_Up_Objective);
    dispatchEvent(event);
}

private function mouseDownFunction(e:MouseEvent):void{
    //e.stopPropagation();
    var event:MouseChangeEvent = new MouseChangeEvent(MouseChangeEvent.Mouse_Down_Objective);
    dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Main App:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseChangeEvent.Mouse_Down_Objective, mouseDownHandler);
stage.addEventListener(MouseChangeEvent.Mouse_Up_Objective, mouseUpHandler);
```

the problem is comp1 dispatch the event but it never catch! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with my tests its not possible to bubble custom event in the component without parent
so you should set parent anyway

Comment: it's answer of my question and it should be closed that's why i leave an answer

Answer (score 0):

The "bubbles"-parameter needs to be set to true in you custom event class.

Comment: it is true : public function MouseChangeEvent(type:String) {
  super(type, true, false);
 }